# You don't have permission to access mp3 file on this server

Tags: apache, centos, http-status-code-403

I have Apache (CentOS) server. If I place some audio file in my directory and run them in my browser then getting **403 forbidden error**. The whole scenario is:

I have created a player in Adobe Captivate and published that into HTML and integrated into my Spring Boot application. It is working fine on my local machine but after pushing it to server. I am getting **Forbidden Error** when my player gets loaded and unable to load audio files (mp3) format.

**Below is my configuration file:**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/player
    <Directory /var/www/html/player>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
  
    Redirect / https://www.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R,L]
    
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/eldtplayer-error-log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/eldtplayer-acces-log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/cert/ecdl/ssl.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/cert/ecdl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/cert/ecdl/caclient.cer

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/player
    <Directory /var/www/html/player>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
</VirtualHost>
```

screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot to display 403 error]

[image: Screenshot to display 403 error]

Comment: You might want to add <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory> and test.

Comment: @Riz Thank you. Do you have any example to show?

Comment: You can just put it under DocumentRoot.

Comment: I am asking about syntax to write <Directory />. 
<Directory /var/www/html/player>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory> Something like this?

Comment: Yeah, try with `/` and then try to restrict if needed. `<Directory "/"> 
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted 
</Directory>`

Comment: I added those lines, unfortunately didn't worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243374/discussion-between-rakhi-and-riz).